# Regarding Acuracy is low after Training the new data with old Trained weight file

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, object-detection

****Hi,

Thank you for your work.
I have been doing some tests with your yolov3, and I have some questions.

I have trained data and created the weight file.
Next time I add some new data and trained with last created weight file.
*I compared the performance of old weight File and New weight File,While detecting I found the new weight file is giving low Accuracy than the old trained weight File.

I have followed each and every step from your Repository
1.Collected the data of 4 classes (2000 images in each class) and marked the bounding boxes.
2.Made Some Changes in configuration file based on 4 classes
3.Kept for Training until the Average loss decrease down 0.0629 and when I found no Change in the Average loss.
4.Took the last weight file and detected,Accuracy was around 50 %
5.Again I started Training 8k new data of same 4 classes with the same procedure followed ,I have used the last Trained weight as a Pre-trained model for new data
6.While detecting I found the Accuracy is lower than the old Trained weight , I was wondering what was the reason,Let me know if anything wrong.

I also wanted to know how to Improve the Accuracy of this ?

Below Attached Configuration file

```
Testing
batch=1
subdivisions=1
Training

batch=64
subdivisions=64
width=608
height=608
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches=200000
policy=steps
steps=160000,180000
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky
Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear
Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear
Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear
Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear
Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

######################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=27
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 10,13, 16,30, 33,23, 30,61, 62,45, 59,119, 116,90, 156,198, 373,326
classes=4
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 61

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=27
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,13, 16,30, 33,23, 30,61, 62,45, 59,119, 116,90, 156,198, 373,326
classes=4
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 36

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=27
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,13, 16,30, 33,23, 30,61, 62,45, 59,119, 116,90, 156,198, 373,326
classes=4
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1'''

Thank you in Advance,
```

Comment: Is the new data from a comparable source or could the new data be different in some way?

Comment: Also maybe this question is better of on the datascience stackexchange?

Comment: old and new data are same